# How to Populate HTML Service Select Options from Range in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to populate my HTML Service drop down/select option list with all entries included in column A of my Vendor Database tab in the Google Sheet I am working with.  It is currently showing up blank, though, when running.  Any suggestions?

APPS SCRIPT:

```
 function getVendors() {
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = active.getSheetByName("Vendor Database");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow); 
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
  var optionsHTML += "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length;i+=1) {
   optionsHTML = '<option>' + data[i][0] + '</option>';
  };
  return optionsHTML;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
   <body>
 <form>
 <div>
   <select>
       <option> != google.script.run.getVendors(); </option>
      </select>
</div>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `data[i]` is an array. Use `data[i][0]`, to access the first element in the array located at the i-th index of data. Additionally, your for loop overwrites all previous values of `optionsHtml`, because it uses `=` (assignment operator) instead of `+=` (append operator). I'm also not sure what you're trying to do with the line `<option> != ... </option>`.

Comment: Thanks, Tehhowch!  I have updated the code above to reflect your suggestions, and have included them in my actual file, as well.  I am still getting a blank drop down list my UI, though.  Last, I am trying to call the values gotten by the getVendors function into my html UI drop-down with the <option> != ...</option> line in my HTML Code.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You missed a very important recommendation I made about the operator you use. I also recommend you review the Apps Script documentation on `google.script.run`, especially with regards to how to use values the called function provides.

Comment: The amendment I made to the operator may have been in the wrong line.  I added to the var optionHTML line, which is coming up as a bug when I run de-bugger against it.  It should be in the 2nd line of the for loop, though?  I am headed to read up on google.script.run now.

Comment: Am I right in that a SuccessHandler is required to use values called from the specified function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing `optionsHTML` that should be direct assignment, not `+=`. Instead, use the `+=` in the for loop as you'll otherwise be replacing the contents of `optionsHTML` rather than appending to it.

```
function getVendors() {
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = active.getSheetByName("Vendor Database");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow); 
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
    optionsHTML += '<option>' + data[i][0] + '</option>';
  };
  return optionsHTML;
}
```

Make sure you're correctly evaluating the HTML. Because of the way you've set this up, you need to treat your HTML file (I'm assuming it's called Index.html) as a template.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate()
}
```

Finally, in the HTML file, looks like you're using incomplete anchors. Should be `<?!= ... ?>` and then call the function directly. (Also, remove the surrounding `<option></option>` tags as `getVendors()` already provides those.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <select>
        <?!= getVendors(); ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Once you have that working, and if it makes sense to put some more time and care into this, refactor to follow the best practices and [load data asynchronously, not in templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates) by using a client-side script inside the HTML as mentioned by @Cooper.

Comment: Thanks, Diego.  I feel like this gets me closer, but am still getting blanks in the drop down list within the html ui.  Not sure what we're missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something similar that I've done in the past.

Here's the Javascript in the html file:

```
$(function() {
        $('#txt1').val('');
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
          .getSelectOptions();
      });

    function updateSelect(vA)
    {
      var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
      select.options.length = 0; 
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
      {
        select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
      }
    }
```

Here's the pertinent HTML:

```
<select id="sel1"  class="control" style="width:255px;height:35px;margin:10px 0 10px 0;">
      <option value="" selected></option>
   </select>
```

Here's the google script:

```
function getSelectOptions()
{
  sortOptions();
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Options');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var options=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    options.push(vA[i][0]);
  }
  return vA;
}
```

Comment: I think that you should include that it's required to load the jQuery library b/c the OP HTML code doesn't include it. By the other hand I think that in this case the same result could be achieved without using jQuery.