# A drop-down list of cells located in the Google Sheets in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I am trying to get a dropdown list using HTML and Google Script. The options should be taken from the Google Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, my list is empty all the time. The options don't appear. Anyone can help?

**CODE GS**

```
  function getListCars(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var carsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Rejestraut");
  var lastrow = carsheet.getLastRow();
  return carsheet.getRange(2,2,lastrow-1,1);
}
```

**HTML**

```
     ...<script>
function loadCars(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar)

  {
    var carsSelect = document.getElementById("numeryrejestracyjne");
    console.log(ar);

    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value="";
    option.text = "";
    carsSelect.appendChild(option);

    ar.forEach(function(item, index)
    {
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item[1];
      option.text = item[1];
      carsSelect.appendChild("option");
    });
  }).getListCars();
};
</script>

<select id="numeryrejestracyjne">
            </select>
            <script>loadCars();</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49578427/7215091

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771993/7215091

Comment: I have tried it. I still had an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

*[getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) does not return values, it returns a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range). In order to return the values of a range, use [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).*

### Example

```js
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 3, 6, 4)
var values = range.getValues()
```

### References:

- [Class Sheet: getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Class Range: getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

Answer (score 0):

`carsheet.getRange(2,2,lastrow-1,1);` does not return any values it just returns a range.  You should have been able to see that with your console.log(ar) in the withSuccessHandler().