# Display a filtered table below HTML form using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**SOLVED**
Old and new code included. Ideally the table would be filtered by Username on load but I will work on that.

I have an App Script project which is connected to a Google sheet. A user can enter information into an HTML form and on submit the data is then entered into the sheet.
I would like to know how to display the Google Sheet table beneath the form which is filtered based on the value in the form field User Name.

Context: This would be completed by pupils as they progress through Physical Education lessons over the course of 3 years (Key Stage 3/Middle School). They can view their progress over these years and also use real data as part of their project work in GCSE/High School.

**Old Code.gs**

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
  
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
function processForm(formObject){
  var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/MYSPREADSHEETID";
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws=ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var dt = Date();

  ws.appendRow([
    dt,
    formObject.username,
    formObject.name,
    formObject.teacher,
    formObject.form_class,
    formObject.test_type,
    formObject.attempt,
    formObject.rating,
  ]);
}
```

**Old Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <base target="_top">
    <!--INCLUDE REQUIRED EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT AND CSS LIBRARIES-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">Fitness Testing</p>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="first_name">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="teacher">Teacher</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="teacher" name="teacher" placeholder="Select Teacher" required>
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="Mr Donald">Mr Donald</option>
                                <option value="Miss McCrossan">Miss McCrossan</option>
                                <option value="Miss Watson">Miss Watson</option>
                                <option value="Mr Dougan">Mr Dougan</option>
                                <option value="Mr Black">Mr Black</option>
                                <option value="Miss Haydock">Miss Haydock</option>
                                <option value="Mrs Mayne">Mrs Mayne</option>
                                <option value="Mr Parker">Mr Parker</option>
                                <option value="Mrs Thompson">Mrs Thompson</option>
                                <option value="Miss McLarnon">Miss McLarnon</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="form_class">Form Class</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="form_class" name="form_class" required>
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="A1">A1</option>
                                <option value="A2">A2</option>
                                <option value="A3">A3</option>
                                <option value="A4">A4</option>
                                <option value="A5">A5</option>
                                <option value="A6">A6</option>
                                <option value="A7">A7</option>
                                <option value="B1">B1</option>
                                <option value="B2">B2</option>
                                <option value="B3">B3</option>
                                <option value="B4">B4</option>
                                <option value="C1">C1</option>
                                <option value="C2">C2</option>
                                <option value="C3">C3</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="test_type">Test Type</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="test_type" name="test_type" required>
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="Bleep Test">Bleep Test</option>
                                <option value="30 Second Alternate Hand Wall Throw">30 Second Alternate Hand Wall Throw</option>
                                <option value="30 Second Abdominal Sit-up Test">30 Second Abdominal Sit-up Test</option>
                                <option value="Illinois Agility Test">Illinois Agility Test</option>
                                <option value="Stork Stand Test">Stork Stand Test</option>
                                <option value="Sit and Reach Test">Sit and Reach Test</option>
                                <option value="Standing Broad Jump">Standing Broad Jump</option>
                                <option value="35m Sprint Test">35m Sprint Test</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="attempt">Attempt No.</label>
                            <input type="number" id="attempts" name="attempt" min="1" max="5" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="rating">Rating</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="rating" name="rating" required>
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="Excellent">Excellent</option>
                                <option value="Above Average">Above Average</option>
                                <option value="Average">Average</option>
                                <option value="Fair">Fair</option>
                                <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
            </div>     

        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Old JavaScript.html**

```
<script>

 function preventFormSubmit(){
    var forms=document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i=0;i<forms.length;i++){
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
window.addEventListener('load',preventFormSubmit);

function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
  google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

</script>
```

[Current HTML Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ot4l.png)

[Expected Result in Google Sheet table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P08OI.png)

Can someone point me in the right direction? I have tried Google but I can't get anything to 'fit' into my code.

[Code I have tried](https://www.bpwebs.com/pull-data-from-google-sheets-to-html-table/)

**New Code.gs**

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();

}

function getData() {
  var spreadSheetId = ""; //CHANGE
  var dataRange = "Data!A:H"; //CHANGE

  var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange);
  var values = range.values;

  return values;

}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
function processForm(formObject){
  var url="";
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws=ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT","dd-MM-yyyy");
  var username = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail().split("@")[0];

  ws.appendRow([
    dt,
    username,
    formObject.name,
    formObject.teacher,
    formObject.form_class,
    formObject.test_type,
    formObject.attempt,
    formObject.rating,
  ]);
}
```

**New Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <base target="_top">
    <!--INCLUDE REQUIRED EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT AND CSS LIBRARIES-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">Fitness Testing</p>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="teacher">Teacher</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="teacher" name="teacher" placeholder="Select Teacher" required>
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="Mr Donald">Mr Donald</option>
                                <option value="Miss McCrossan">Miss McCrossan</option>
                                <option value="Miss Watson">Miss Watson</option>
                                <option value="Mr Dougan">Mr Dougan</option>
                                <option value="Mr Black">Mr Black</option>
                                <option value="Miss Haydock">Miss Haydock</option>
                                <option value="Mrs Mayne">Mrs Mayne</option>
                                <option value="Mr Parker">Mr Parker</option>
                                <option value="Mrs Thompson">Mrs Thompson</option>
                                <option value="Miss McLarnon">Miss McLarnon</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="form_class">Form Class</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="form_class" name="form_class" required>
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="A1">A1</option>
                                <option value="A2">A2</option>
                                <option value="A3">A3</option>
                                <option value="A4">A4</option>
                                <option value="A5">A5</option>
                                <option value="A6">A6</option>
                                <option value="A7">A7</option>
                                <option value="B1">B1</option>
                                <option value="B2">B2</option>
                                <option value="B3">B3</option>
                                <option value="B4">B4</option>
                                <option value="C1">C1</option>
                                <option value="C2">C2</option>
                                <option value="C3">C3</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="test_type">Test Type</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="test_type" name="test_type" required>
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="Bleep Test">Bleep Test</option>
                                <option value="30 Second Alternate Hand Wall Throw">30 Second Alternate Hand Wall Throw</option>
                                <option value="30 Second Abdominal Sit-up Test">30 Second Abdominal Sit-up Test</option>
                                <option value="Illinois Agility Test">Illinois Agility Test</option>
                                <option value="Stork Stand Test">Stork Stand Test</option>
                                <option value="Sit and Reach Test">Sit and Reach Test</option>
                                <option value="Standing Broad Jump">Standing Broad Jump</option>
                                <option value="35m Sprint Test">35m Sprint Test</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="attempt">Attempt No.</label>
                            <input type="number" id="attempts" name="attempt" min="1" max="5" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="rating">Rating</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="rating" name="rating" required>
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="Excellent">Excellent</option>
                                <option value="Above Average">Above Average</option>
                                <option value="Average">Average</option>
                                <option value="Fair">Fair</option>
                                <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <br>
                      <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFilter()" placeholder="Enter Username...">
                      <br>
                      <table id="myTable" border="1" cellpadding="5px" >
                      <?var tableData = getData();?>
                      <?for(var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) { ?>
                        <?if(i == 0) { ?>
                          <tr>
                          <?for(var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) { ?>
                          <th><?= tableData[i][j] ?></th>
                          <? } ?>
                          </tr>
                        <? } else { ?>
                          <tr>
                          <?for(var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) { ?>
                          <td><?= tableData[i][j] ?></td>
                          <? } ?>
                          </tr>
                        <? } ?>
                      <? } ?>
                      </table>
                </div>
            </div>     

        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**New JavaScript.html**

```
<script>

function myFilter() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, filter2, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > 0) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

 function preventFormSubmit(){
    var forms=document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i=0;i<forms.length;i++){
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
window.addEventListener('load',preventFormSubmit);

function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
  google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

</script>
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `display a dynamic table beneath the form which displays the rows from the table which are filtered based on the User Name entered`. And also, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your expected goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: I have tried to edit my original post as best possible. I would like a table below my HTML form which displays the data from my google sheet. The data I would like displayed is all the rows which contain the matching user name typed into the user name field in the form. So far the code only displays the form.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. In your updated question, you provided "Current HTML Output". Can you provide your expected result? And, I cannot still understand the relationship between `the Google Sheet table beneath the form which is filtered based on the value in the form field User Name` and your showing script and "Current HTML Output".

Comment: Related question: [How to Populate HTML Service Select Options from Range in Google Sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49584078/1330560).

Comment: @Tanaike I have added another image of my table. When the HTML form is submitted the data is added to the Google Sheet. When the form loads I would like the table to be visible in the HTML form page. When the user types in their User Name in the User Name field, the table will filter to only include rows that have the value of the User Name field.

Comment: May I observe out that 1) there is redundant data in requiring both UserName and Name 2) neither the userName nor the Name are sourced or validated from the spreadsheet, so there is a substantial risk of data entry error

Comment: @Tedinoz The requirement for the name and username is twofold. The name is for teachers to see which pupil has completed (username naming convention is jbloggs123) and the username will be for the filter. In the future, I would like to be able to extract the left portion of the email login as that contains the username already. Validation still needs to be added, the project is not live. The table feature needs added first.

Comment: @Tanaike I will try and explain again. Students will complete the HTML form (link 1) with their relevant information about fitness after their lesson. This data will be stored in the linked Google Sheet (link 2). Teachers will have access to this to view the data. Imagine students have submitted several entries of the form. When they enter their Username in the form field they should be able to see a table appear under the form displaying all of their data from the Google Sheet.

Comment: Added a link to the code I have tried. There have been many variations of this from other sites. The code runs and no errors appear, but nothing appears on the HTML form.